# C# HttpClient post response content-type application/json

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have to call an API in my C# class with httpclient. API need the content-type header, I want to get the response as JSON so I add content-type: application/json to headers in Postman and do the post request and it works perfectly:

[image]

But if I write something else in content-type API returns html code.
I have to do the exactly same thing as Postman in C#. Here is my example code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("adress");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "adress");
request.Content = new StringContent(myjson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var y = await client.SendAsync(request);
var x = await y.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But the result is always HTML not JSON.

Comment: Please dont hit me :s ... is the HTML page you see an error page?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting but solved in this way :

```
request.Content = new StringContent(myjson, Encoding.UTF8);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
request.Content.Headers.Add("No-Paging", "true");
```